# Is it allowed to add react-jsx code blocks with js?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

What I have is a simple render function with some conditions.

```
class AwesomeTestClass {
  constructor() { /* constructor stuff */ }
  reder() {
    let OUT = (<Text> basic text 1 </Text>);

    if (someCondition) {
      OUT += (<Text> add some condition text </Text>);
    } else {
      OUT += (<Text> add other condition text </Text>);
    }

    OUT += (<Text> end of awesome text </Text>);

    return (
      <View>
        {OUT}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I try to accomplish the following output:

```
<View>
<Text> basic text 1 </Text>
<Text> add some condition text </Text>
<Text> end of awesome text </Text>
</View>
```

My error is as followed:

> RawText `"[object Object][object Object]"` must be wrapped in an explicit `<Text>` component.

So I wonder the following:

- Is there a way to use the `+=` operator on react-jsx variables in js like js does with a string?
- Is there a way to use the `+` operator on react-jsx variables in js like js does with a string?

If not, is there a way:

- To cast from a String to JSX
- To cast from JSX to String

Following things I tried:

- Using JSX:

  ```
  // += visible at the top

  let OUT = (<Text>Awe</Text>);
  OUT = OUT + (<Text>some</Text>);
  ```

  Error output:

  > RawText `"[object Object][object Object]"` must be wrapped in an explicit `<Text>` component.
- Using Strings:

  ```
  let OUT = "<Text>Awe</Text>";
  OUT = OUT + "<Text>some</Text>";

  let OUT = "<Text>Awe</Text>";
  OUT += "<Text>some</Text>";
  ```

  Error output:

  > RawText `"<Text>Awe</Text><Text>some</Text>"` must be wrapped in an explicit `<Text>` component.
- Using String Casting:

  ```
  let OUT = String(<Text>Awe</Text>);
  OUT = OUT + String(<Text>some</Text>);

  let OUT = String(<Text>Awe</Text>);
  OUT += String(<Text>some</Text>);
  ```

  Error output:

  > RawText `"[object Object][object Object]"` must be wrapped in an explicit `<Text>` component.
- Using String Casting with String:

  ```
  let OUT = String(<Text>Awe</Text>);
  OUT = OUT + "<Text>some</Text>";

  let OUT = String(<Text>Awe</Text>);
  OUT += "<Text>some</Text>";
  ```

  Error output:

  > RawText `"[object Object]<Text>some</Text>"` must be wrapped in an explicit `<Text>` component.

**Why do I try?**
Well I don not want to move each statement to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the components into an array and render that:

```
render() {
  let OUT = [(<Text key={1}> basic text 1 </Text>)];

  if (someCondition) {
    OUT.push(<Text key={2}> add some condition text </Text>);
  } else {
    OUT.push(<Text key={3}> add other condition text </Text>);
  }

  OUT.push(<Text key={4}> end of awesome text </Text>);

  return (
    <View>
      {OUT}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Note that I added a hardcoded key in this case. If you use a loop to render these items, you will need a key so react can distinguish each component if they are dynamically added or removed. Do not use the index as the key as [it's an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Comment: Awesome I used the array method and tried to add each component and render that. But I can just render the array.

Comment: @RensvWalstijn With conditional rendering you won't need keys. This is not the best react solution unless your array is truly dynamic (e.g. array of items read from server). Or create an array of *strings* and then `map` the array of strings to `<Text>` components in `render`.

Comment: @Sulthan No the `<Text>` components where a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe just use one of the conditional rendering strategies, I would propose something like this:

```
return (
   <View>
     { someCondition ? 
        (<Text> add some condition text </Text>):
        (<Text> add other condition text </Text>)
     }
     <Text> end of awesome text </Text>
   </View>
);
```

Look at: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html